# Получение списка task из Битрикс24

Tags: php, rest, битрикс24

Решаю задачу, такую, как подключение (авторизация) и получение списка задач из Битрикс24.

По данной ссылке я нашел общий пример работы такого рода: [ссылка](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=4997)
Однако, непонятно, как там подключать библиотеки, и просто фрагменты текста не дают полного понимая происходящего. Потому прошу помощи у тех, кто работал с Битрикс24, кто может дать ссылки на конкретные примеры?

```
$obApp = new CBitrixPHPAppTransport($accessToken, 'http://my.bitrix24.ru');
$arPlannerTasks = array(array('task.planner.getlist', array()),
array('task.items.getlist', array('ORDER' => array("ID" => 'desc'), 'FILTER' => array('ID' => '$result[0]'))));
$arTasksBatch = $obApp->batch($arPlannerTasks);
```

Откуда идет инициализация объекта CBitrixPHPAppTransport? Где брать эту библиотеку, в которой лежат такие объекты?
Эти бы ответы помогли бы мне.

Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тегам, у вас приложение третьего типа. Для них алгоритм такой:

1. Авторизуетесь на портале.
2. Выполняете запрос https://portal.bitrix24.ru/oauth/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=app.xxx.yyy. Вместе с запросом отправляете куки авторизации.
3. Парсите из полученного html код авторизации.
4. С этим кодом делаете запрос https://portal.bitrix24.ru/oauth/token/?grant_type=authorization_code&code=%CODE%&client_id=app.xxx.yyy&client_secret=foo-bar&scope=tasks_extended,task.
5. Получаете json, содержащий токен.
6. Делаете запрос списка задач (ну или любой другой): http://portal.bitrix24.ru/rest/task.item.list?auth=%TOKEN%

Comment: Я отредактировал свой вопрос. Откуда берутся объекты CBitrixPHPAppTransport? И еще если можно через GET параметры передавать параметры, то можно делать также это и в коде PHP. Не так ли?

Comment: Что касается CBitrixPHPAppTransport: https://bxapi.ru/?module_id=socialservices&class=CBitrixPHPAppTransport  
Вторую часть вашего вопроса я вообще не понял. Я работаю с апи Б24 прямыми http-запросами, без всяких обёрток, если вы об этом.

Comment: Да именно об обертке есть вопрос, чтобы оформить в виде своего класса. А так за ответ спасибо! Плюсую!

Comment: третий пункт я не до конца смог разобрать, где именно находится код авторизации? В поле hidden gПод кодом Fcheck_key или это другой код? Для меня проблема не выдрать какой-либо код, а найти его.

Comment: Откройте эту страницу в браузере. Огромные цифры - это и есть код. Проблема в том, что на этот запрос всегда возвращается html (например, когда вы не авторизованы), поэтому в коде получение кода осложняется проверками. Селектор у кода вот такой: doc.querySelector('.oauth-code-shower h1')

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521329/3549 вот описал проблему. Не смог прикрепить свой вопрос к дискуссии нашей ветки, потому написал отдельным ответом тут.

Comment: Конечно, у вас не работает, ведь я же написал, что вместе с запросом нужно отправить куки. Вы в ответ получаете форму авторизации, в которой кода нет. Об этом я написал в прошлом комментарии.

Comment: Не могли бы более точно сказать, что нужно передать в куках мне на сервер? Я вроде, как уже в юрле передаю код юзера, а затем еще секретный код. Можно практический пример маленький, для понятности)? Простите за наглость, если прошу многое)

Comment: Вы передаёте id приложения и его секретный токен. Дополнительно вам нужно передать как раз id пользователя в куках. Для этого вам нужно выполнить первый шаг из моего ответа - авторизоваться на портале. В качестве примера можете воспользоваться моей статьёй (https://habrahabr.ru/post/278849/). Сайт другой, но шаги и принципы абсолютно те же. В конце есть ссылка на репозиторий с кодом.

Comment: Уколов, можно вопрос? Почему при выполнении такого кода (или просто юрла), оно выдает ошибку, что неизвестный клиент?:  https://ctweb.bitrix24.ru/oauth/authorize/?client_id=app.56f4af166abe54.38840653&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://ctweb.bitrix24.ru/second.php

Comment: Не знаю, не сталкивался, кажется с такой ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тестовая страница, где я все это делаю:
http://maps.fantastic-book.ru

Код пишу такой:

```
function connectBitrix24($url) {
    $ResultMSG = Array();
    $this -> longURL = '';
    $this -> houseurl = $url;
    $this -> longURL = 'https://'.$this->houseurl. '/oauth/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id='.$this->client_id;

    $htmldata = @file_get_contents($this -> longURL) ;

    if ($htmldata == = false) {
        $ResultMSG[htmltext] = '';
        $ResultMSG[errormsg] = "Ошибка подключения к данному юрлу. URL = ".$this->longURL;
    } else {
        $ResultMSG[htmltext] = $htmldata;
        $ResultMSG[errormsg] = '';
    }
    return $ResultMSG;
}
```

Вызов делаю так:

```
$id_key = 'app.56f4af1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$newObj = new Workbitrix24($id_key, $client_secret);

$text = $newObj->connectBitrix24('xwebx.bitrix24.ru');
echo "<br/>";
print_r($text);
```

В итоге получаю форму, в которой я пытаюсь найти Ваш селектор, но там ничего такого нет.

Функция по выдиранию кода есть, только я не знаю, где именно есть этот код авторизации:

```
function AuthorizeIsSystem($ArrResult) {
    if (is_array($ArrResult)) {
        $position = 0;
        $position = strripos($ArrResult[htmltext], 'backurl');
        if ($position > 0) {
            $frag = substr($ArrResult[htmltext], $position, 500); //strlen($ResultMSG[htmltext]) - $position
            $pos2 = strripos($frag, 'check_key');
            $frag2 = substr($frag, $pos2 + 1, strlen($frag) - $pos2); //strlen($ResultMSG[htmltext]) - $position

            return $frag2;
        } else return 0;
    }
}
```